# Tesseract ocr output with single characters in between the detected text

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to use Tesseract to extract from the below image,

[image]

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='-c preserve_interword_spaces=1 --psm 1 --oem 1')
```

Here is the result from tesseract 4 ocr,

```
print(text)

Wrote Datastream application 
e Used Kafka to get the accounts
```

If you see the bullet point in the image is converted to `e`, I found several such points in document converted into single characters in ascii

If anyone is familiar with such issue and have a solution please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suggestion, maybe its better to remove the bullet-points.

- One solution for removing the bullet-point is applying `adaptive-threshold`
- If we apply `adaptive-threshold` to the current image:

  - [image]
- Now if we read it:

  - ```
    Wrote Datastream application |
    Used Kafka to get the accounts
    ```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("4XMue.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 131)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
```

---

Please let me tell you that my example code, may not work for every image. Since an image may have different artifacts or require additional processing. You may need to change the `block-size` and `C` parameters of the `adaptive-threshold`. Therefore, please start with reading the [adaptive-threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

Comment: But I think, tesseract already binarize the image right using otsu algorithm? So, when we do it twice don't quality degrade on large and dense document

Comment: Tesseract OCR internally applies Otsu binarization method. However this method selects an optimal global threshold according to image histogram. If there is a shadow on the image, tesseract will fail extracting the characters. [source](https://github.com/pedrofrodenas/image-thresholding-OCR)

Comment: but if we do it twice, won't it decrease the quality of the image?

Comment: `but if we do it twice`? you mean applying OTSU thresholding two times? If so, I did not apply OTSU thresholding to the image. If you look at my `adaptive-threhsold` method,  I only used `cv2.THRESH_BINARY`.

Comment: We are preprocessing images for removing the artifacts from the image. Therefore, multiple-preprocessing shouldn't decrease the quality of the image. Otherwise we can't gather the features from the image.